# Ajax functions with variables

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've got a table and fields with "onclick" option:

```
<td class="name" onclick="ajax_update_entries('<?php echo $field['Player']['name']; ?>')">
```

It calls function:

```
function ajax_update_entries(player_name)
  {
  $.post('http://mysite.com/entries/get_entries/' + player_name, function(data)
    {
    $('#gameText').html(data);
    });
  setTimeout('ajax_update_entries(player_name)', 30000);
  }
```

What it does very good is going to requested page after click on the table field. What it does very wrong, it doesn't recognize "player_name" parameter in setTimeout which should refresh it. In the Opera console it returns:

> Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: player_name

and IE says there's no definition of 'player_name'.

But on the other hand, if I go with:

```
setTimeout('ajax_update_entries("Michael Jordan")', 30000);
```

it works and will refresh the page with parameter: Michael Jordan.

So my question is: what's wrong with this script? I mean, why is the variable `player_name` suddenly forgotten? How to fix it?

Comment: @bfavaretto's answer should fix it for you - in your original code, you have player_name inside the quotes, that makes it a string, not a variable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ajax_update_entries(player_name);
}, 30000);
```

The variable was not forgotten, the problem is that you were passing the function call as a string to `setTimeout`. What happens then, is that it goes through `eval` (which is [not good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21), by the way), without its original context, so the javascript interpreter does not know what to pass. Hence the error.

Comment: Alternatively, you could bind the arg as such: `setTimeout(ajax_update_entries.bind(this, player_name), 30000);`

Comment: @TheSmose Yes, but it should be noted that it won't work on older browsers (like IE8).

Comment: @bfavaretto: Thanks, there's no more error in console. The problem is it still doesn't work as it should: on default I want to have all the entries loaded (so I call it with 0): <body onload="ajax_update_entries(0);> . After changing setTimeout function as you said it constantly switches between default option (0) and chosen parameter (player_name). Has my script gone mad? Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: @Adam That's because the code "remembers" that zero you passed, and will keep calling `ajax_update_entries(0)` every 30 secs. I suggest not setting the timer if the argument is zero, i.e., `if(player_name != 0) { /* setTimeout... */ }`.